# Drupal core - SQL injection aftermath procedures

Tags: redhat, mariadb

Our production site we run has potentially been compromised as we saw a big spike in network traffic, which brought down the site.

Since theft has potentially already happen before our patching, what steps should we go through informing our client. Do they need to make any password changes for the admin login, etc. Anything else that is relevant? Do we need to change the db password on our server etc.

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes, all of the above.

There is a flow chart on the [Drupalgeddon project page] (https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) that you can follow to help ensure you are dealing with a clean site.

Good luck